# Retrieving relative table data by sort order in symfony 1.4

Tags: php, doctrine, foreign-keys, symfony-1.4

I have a relative table with a column titled sort_order. When I retrieve the values from the associated table, I would like them to sort by this column rather than id.

**indexSuccess:**

```
<?php foreach ($videos as $video): ?>
    <?php $videoAssets = $video->getVideoHubAssets(); ?>
...
```

and I want to do something like

```
<?php $videoAssets = $video->getVideoHubAssets()->orderBy("sort_order ASC"); ?>
```

but this is not correct. Do I have to work this out in the actions first?

**actions**

```
$this->videos = Doctrine::getTable('videosHub')->getAllVideos();
```

**tableClass**

```
public function getAllVideos(){
  return $this->createQuery()->setPublishStatus()->orderBy('featured DESC, title')->execute();
  }
```

The action query is pulling from a separate table that has relations to the asset table. What is the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new method for your video class.

For example :

**indexSuccess:**

```
<?php foreach ($videos as $video): ?>
    <?php $videoAssets = $video->getOrderedVideoHubAssets(); ?>
...
```

**class**

```
public function getOrderedVideoHubAssets(){
    return Doctrine_Core::getTable('VideoHubAsset')->createQuery('a')
           ->leftJoin('a.Video v')
           ->where('a.video_id = ?', $this->getId())
           ->orderBy('a.sort_order ASC')
           ->execute();
}
```

Comment: That got it, but it raises a question about the benefits of creating table relations. If you have to call a separate query to get the associated records by Id, then sort, what is the real benefit of creating the relations in the first place? Even if they were not bound by a foreign key, you could still do the exact same thing.

Comment: This is the method I use, but it may not be the most optimized. There is probably a way to make it simpler and more optimized using the "first" relation (defined in schema.yml). So if someone has another solution, let us know!